# php error Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

I have this code segment to upload a file. I get this this error when I upload big files like (300MB). Files below 20 MB work fine.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 813695000 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\processor.php on line 219
```

**Note:** I already did lot SO and google search, but failed to fix this.

**Reason I found:**  Reason - `file_get_contents()` fetches entire string of data into variable. that variable is stored in hosts memory. 
                           When string is greater than the size dedicated to PHP process

```
$data = file_get_contents( $path );
    //echo $data;

    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $data );
    $query_insert = "INSERT INTO Upload(Name,Type,Size,Content) VALUES('Tour Photo','jpg',234, '$data')";
    $result_insert = mysqli_query( $con, $query_insert ) or die ("<hr>Couldn't execute INSERT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<h4>New sport added to the database</h4>";
```

**UPDATED code for @RedPoppy**

```
        $fo = fopen ( $path, 'r' );
        if( is_readable($path) ){
            echo "*** Uploaded file is readable ***<br><br>";
        }

        $data = fread ( $fo, filesize($path) ); //read entire file
        $data = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con, $data );
        fclose( $fo );
```

Comment: Why are you storing files in the database anyway? The standard approach to this is to store the file in the filesystem, and the filepath to it in the database

Comment: thanks for the comment. But any solution for this?

Comment: That *is* the solution. You won't get a memory error if you're not stuffing 300MB's worth into a variable, but copy the entire file onto the filesystem itself. Stuffing MySQL rows with 300MB (or more) isn't going to help your database performance either.

Comment: is there anyway to store that large file to database without storing in the variable?

Comment: You'd have to take a fragment of the file at a time and append this fragment to its location in your database until you've got the whole file in the database. You will not be able to circumvent storing the file in memory if you wish to add it to the database but you can ease it in without using 300mb of memory at a time. Although I would recommend using Oldskool's suggestion if possible.

Comment: store the file in the filesystem having renamed it to a unique name.. write a db record with the filename and the filepath. Job done.

Comment: @DevDonkey I tested it. But same problem :(

Comment: Storing the file in the filesystem and just storing a filepath in the database won't give you the same problem, because it doesn't entail loading the file into memory

Answer (score 2):

assuming that your `Content` is a binary blob and that you actually have a reason for storing files in the database (there can be a few, most generally it's not recommended for operational reasons), you could allow large file uploads by reading pieces of the file and inserting with an update clause (or just doing an insert followed by updates). Use `fopen`, `fread` and `fclose`. Please be aware that with very large files you might have trouble from other areas, like the webserver becoming unresponsive etc.

Comment: Your ideas are correct. I used fopen, fread, and fclose(). But I still get the same error. I want to save this large file to database although it is not good practice.

Comment: It appears you still read whole file into memory. Read it in a for loop, in say 5mb chunks

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. I am in difficult to code that. I am a beginner. I can understand what you mean. But can you publish the code segment?

Comment: I am affraid that won't help you much. Try reading up on it, it is actually not that difficult. Just read the docs for fread

Answer (score 1):

The Problem ist that you're about to store files in your DB. That's insane.
The only (logical) solution to avoid this error is to upload the file to your filesystem and save the path/reference/key in your database.
Otherwise, you will keep getting that error plus your DB perfomance is beyond oblivion.

Or you try this: `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`but I don't recommend this.

EDIT: You can also edit your .htaccess file: add `php_value memory_limit xxxM` while xxx is your maximal size in Megabytes

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); I used this. but the problem still exist. Do I need to restart my Wampserver after using this in the top of my php script?

Comment: Hm. You won't need a restart as far as i know. Try my edit